# RSACryptoServiceProvider Conversion from C# to VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, public-key-encryption

I was sent the following code block by a third party client to allow me access some of there web services:

```
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCryptoServiceProvider = new
    RSACryptoServiceProvider(dwKeySize);
    rsaCryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString(xmlString);
    int keySize = dwKeySize / 8;
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(inputString);
    int maxLength = keySize - 42;
    int dataLength = bytes.Length;
    int iterations = dataLength / maxLength;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i <= iterations; i++)
   {
     byte[] tempBytes = new byte[(dataLength - maxLength * i > maxLength) ?
     maxLength : dataLength - maxLength * i];
     Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, maxLength * i, tempBytes, 0, tempBytes.Length);
     byte[] encryptedBytes = rsaCryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt(tempBytes, true);
     Array.Reverse(encryptedBytes);
     stringBuilder.Append(Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes));
    }
    return stringBuilder.ToString();
```

And I have converted it from C# to VB.Net:

```
    Dim objEncrypter As New RSACryptoServiceProvider(Me.m_intKeySize)
    objEncrypter.FromXmlString(m_strEncryptionString)
    Dim intKeySize = Me.m_intKeySize / 8
    Dim objByte() As Byte = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(p_strXMLString.InnerXml)
    Dim intMaxLength As Integer = intKeySize - 42
    Dim intDataLength As Integer = objByte.Length
    Dim intIterations As Integer = intDataLength / intMaxLength
    Dim strResult As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder

    For intCounter As Integer = 0 To intIterations
        Dim tempBytes(IIf(intDataLength - intMaxLength * intCounter > intMaxLength, intMaxLength, intDataLength - intMaxLength * intCounter)) As Byte
        Buffer.BlockCopy(objByte, intMaxLength * intCounter, tempBytes, 0, tempBytes.Length)
        Dim objEncryptedBytes() As Byte = objEncrypter.Encrypt(tempBytes, True)
        Array.Reverse(objEncryptedBytes)
        strResult.Append(Convert.ToBase64String(objEncryptedBytes))
    Next

    Return strResult.ToString
```

The problem is it keeps throwing the following exception:

System.ArgumentException: Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.

I can see what it's doing, trying to address areas of the byte array the don't exists but I can't see why. Unless either the C# code doesn't work or something has gotten lost in the translation. Any suggestions?

Kevin

Comment: which line throws the exception? The `BlockCopy`?

Comment: as an aside, you don't need hungarian notation in VB either.

Comment: The line         Dim tempBytes(IIf(intDataLength - intMaxLength * intCounter > intMaxLength, intMaxLength, intDataLength - intMaxLength * intCounter)) As Byte
And I do if I wan't to keep my job :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB arrays are declared using the upper bound, not the length.
So use:

```
Dim tempBytes(If(dataLength - maxLength * i > maxLength, maxLength, dataLength - maxLength * i) - 1) As Byte
```

Also, you should use VB integer division for the following:

```
Dim iterations As Integer = dataLength \ maxLength
```

Comment: Ok, now the line is giving me System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

Comment: @user1708468: Which line?

Comment: @user1708468: The 'tempBytes' declaration or the 'iterations' declaration?

Comment: @user1708468: You also need to change the 'iterations' declarations to use VB integer division - when I do that I do not get an OverflowException.